# How can I make jCarousel to have width 100% instead of specifing in px?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I am working on asp.net and Jquery. I tried many carousel but they all need to specify the width in px. Doing so my website looks abnormal on different resolution.
How can I make it to occupy the whole width available to it?

Has any one know any other plugin which is easy and support this function?

Comment: Which carousel plugin are you using now?

Comment: jcarousel plugin @http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jcarousel

Comment: Can't you edit the skin.css files? Specify width of 100% there instead of the fixed ones?

Answer (score 1):

You can by remove the width on the container and set the clip to 100% on the css as:

```
.jcarousel-container-horizontal 
{
    /* width: 275px;  <--- remove it */
}

.jcarousel-clip-horizontal 
{
    width: 100%;     /*<-- set it 100%*/
    height: 75px;
}
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/hgYmt/

base on this demo page :  http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

Because I can't modify the css files, I use the important, but the idea is the same.

Comment: I did it but it showed all the item and expanded the width of my page.

Comment: @user2294729 This is what you ask or not ? 100% / full page.

Comment: yes but 100% is expanding my page width also. instead 100% should fit the whole area without adding horizontal scrollbar. i mean to fit only the available area.

Comment: @user2294729 Work with your css, I can not magically fix it for your on all aspects. Even in my pages I work with my css for hours to make them looks as I have won them, so work you too with your css.